# 403 forbidden issue in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, http-status-code-403

I have a JMeter test with the following configuration:

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2017-08-18 12:45:02 IST
Load time: 304
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 304
Size in bytes: 209
Headers size in bytes: 206
Body size in bytes: 3
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 403
Response message: Forbidden
```

Unfortunately it fails with the following response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Date: Fri, 18 Aug 2017 07:15:03 GMT
Server: openresty/1.9.3.1
X-Vcap-Request-Id: c9307775-0897-4fbd-5d45-e2e7c11cb1b1
Content-Length: 3
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `HTTP 403 - Forbidden` is returned, when the request is valid, but the caller has no permissions. You probably need to incorporate an authentication header in your request.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Can you please any provide any docs on this sentence structure.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can have a lot of causes:

- missing content-type header
- missing authentication token
- missing CSRF token
- failing authentication before access to url
- ...

Can you show the request you send ?

Comment: GET https://tix-stage.run.aws-usw02-pr.ice.predix.io/SbomProxyService/api/services/fetchQuoteListDetails?quoteStatus=QUOTED

Comment: Cookie Data:
predix-seed-session=c4krSuplzYEub9i2pRLEAA..|1503044094|xTCnnFanHQ3c5sL9d9Co2A..|amE3p_-6aqrNvZcxEpKQgvRtNSM.

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36
Referer: https://tix-stage.run.aws-usw02-pr.ice.predix.io/value-master-list
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Host: tix-stage.run.aws-usw02-pr.ice.predix.io

Comment: Please find above two comments for the request sent.

Answer (score 0):

I found that OpenResty requires User-Agent header. It will throw 403 Forbidden if User-Agent header doesn't exist.

JMeter do not attach this header automatically like most other apps do hence returning 403 Forbidden.